# how do i make open two file with same name under 1 variable for difference function?

Tags: python, file, variables, input

i make 2 loop that has to open 2 same file name req.txt. i want to input only 1 file but read by the two loop. i had done below but not valid.. error msg

> line 32, in 
>       with open(requestfile,'r') as rqfile: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

```
onefile= './req.txt'
with open(onefile, 'r') as requestfile:
#rqfile = rrr = requestfile

    with open(requestfile,'r') as rqfile:
        for line in rqfile:           
            line = line.rstrip()        
            if line.startswith('Referer: '): 
                urll = line[9:]      
            elif line.startswith('Cookie: '):
                cookie=line[18:]
            elif line.startswith('Host: '):
                host=line[6:]

    rqfile.close()

with open(requestfile,'r') as rrr:
    for i, line in enumerate(rrr):  

        if i == 14:

            username = line[:line.index('=')]
            password = line[line.index('&') + 1:line.index('=', line.index('=') + 1)]
                print(username, password)
rrr.close()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the second and third with?

Comment: im sorry for mistakes..

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open the file by its file name instead of a file object:

```
onefile = './req.txt'

with open(onefile, 'r') as rqfile:
    for line in rqfile:  # loop over the file directly
        line = line.rstrip()  # remove the trailing newline
        if line.startswith('Referer: '):  # start cari text tertentu
            urll = line[9:]  # get text start with lajur 9
        elif line.startswith('Cookie: '):
            cookie = line[18:]
        elif line.startswith('Host: '):
            host = line[6:]

with open(onefile, 'r') as rrr:
    for i, line in enumerate(rrr):
        if i == 14:
            username = line[:line.index('=')]
            password = line[line.index('&') + 1:line.index('=', line.index('=') + 1)]
            print(username, password)
```